# MS Access stores the incorrect DateTime.MinValue?

Tags: c#, ms-access, datetime

I have a problem when storing `DateTime.MinValue` into a field (as Date/Time type) in MS Access. Printing this out prior to storing in database, I get "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM", which is expected. However after retrieving the same value out of the database I get "1/1/2001 12:00:00 AM" (note the year 2001 instead of year 1).

This is obviously incorrect! Anyone have any ideas?

Note, that I am using DateTime.MinValue as someone suggested as invalid date/time, because DateTime cannot be null value.

The code to write to database is:

```
    public static bool StartNow(string profileID, string startNotes)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM shifts WHERE profile_id=@profile_id AND closed=false;");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profile_id", profileID);

        // A new shift should NEVER be started with another open shift.
        OleDbDataReader reader = Database.Read(cmd);
        if (reader.HasRows)
            return false;

        cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO shifts(profile_id, start, stop, start_log, stop_log, start_notes, stop_notes, closed) VALUES(@profile_id, @start, @stop, @start_log, @stop_log, @start_notes, @stop_notes, @closed);");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profile_id", profileID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", RoundUp(now, 30).ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stop", DateTime.MinValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start_log", now.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stop_log", DateTime.MinValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start_notes", startNotes);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stop_notes", "");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@closed", false);
        // TODO: need to set default values for stop, stop_log and stop_notes
        return Database.Write(cmd) == 1 ? true : false;
    }
```

This is the code to read back in the date and time:

```
    public static List<ShiftView> TodaysShifts()
    {
        List<ShiftView> shifts = new List<ShiftView>();

        // INFO: Not intended to retrieve a lot of records as there is no caching....
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT profiles.profile_id, profiles.full_name, shifts.start, shifts.stop, shifts.start_log, shifts.stop_log, shifts.start_notes, shifts.stop_notes FROM shifts, profiles WHERE (shifts.start>=@today) AND (shifts.profile_id=profiles.profile_id);");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@today", DateTime.Today);
        OleDbDataReader reader = Database.Read(cmd);

        while(reader.Read())
        {
            shifts.Add(new ShiftView(
                reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("profile_id")), 
                reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("full_name")),
                reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("start")),
                reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("stop")),
                reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("start_log")),
                reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("stop_log")),
                reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("start_notes")),
                reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("stop_notes"))
                ));
        }

        return shifts;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Jon Skeet :-

> Basically, don't use DateTime.MinValue to represent a missing value.
>   You can't use DateTime.MinValue in a SQL Server DateTime field, as SQL
>   Server has a minimum value of the start of 1753.
>
> Instead, make your property a Nullable (aka
>   DateTime?), and set it to null when you don't have a value. Also make
>   sure your database field is nullable. Then you just need to make sure
>   that that null ends up as a NULL value in the database. Exactly how
>   you do that will depend on your data access.

and you can give a try to use **SqlDateTime.MinValue** instead of **DateTime.MinVaue**

Answer (score 4):

In Microsoft Access **"Valid date values range from -657,434 (January 1, 100 A.D.) to 2,958,465 (December 31, 9999 A.D.). Valid time values range from .0 to .9999, or 23:59:59."** (ref: [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/format-the-date-and-time-field-in-access-HA010341474.aspx#_Toc260216068).) So, you cannot store "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" in an Access `Date/Time` field.

Comment: Best way round it is to use separate year, month and day fields with valid values of month from 1-12 and day from 1-31. Doesn't stop invalid dates but better than a string.